# Сослагательное наклонение vs. инфинитив

Tags: синтаксис, сослагательное-наклонение

Пользуясь тем, что здесь ([Сложноподчиненные предложения (СПП) русского языка | manuscriptgames.org](http://praha.manuscriptgames.org/)) написано про СПП цели я пыталась перефразировать следующие предложения:

> (1) Мы приехали в магазин, чтобы купить апельсины. = Мы приехали
>   купить.

Я попробовала сделать обратно: из инфинитива к СПП цели:

> (2) Я уговорила его обратиться к психотерапевту. →  (3) Я уговорила
>   его, чтобы он обратился к психотерапевту.

Русская коллега сказала, что вы так не говорите, потому что "не звучит", но она не могла объяснить почему.

Я сама не знаю, почему "не звучит", когда субъекты различные и согласно правилу можно использовать сослагательное наклонение. Или дело в семантике глагола "уговорить"?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ну почему же, можно сказать и: *"Мы приехали в магазин купить апельсинов".* Но с "уговорить" действительно "чтобы" плохо сочетается.

Answer (score 2):

В этих предложениях - первоначальных и преображённых - и не ночевало сослагательное наклонение!

1. Нет, не "мы приехали купить", а "мы приехали купить апельсины", за ними и ехали, а не просто шопинговали.
2. "Уговорить, чтобы" приводится как [пример в словарной статье](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), но мы действительно так не говорим, мы уговариваем сделать что-то (как в том предложении, из которого произросло это "чтобы"; тогда глагол надо менять, и это никак не связано с сослагательным наклонением! Вот "упросила" годится, но это более "домашнее", нежели нейтральное "уговорить"...

А "порекомендовала" - более книжное.

А знаете, что могла иметь в виду русская коллега под "не звучит"? "Его, чтобы он".

Comment: Спасибо Вам всем за ответы! я думала, что "бы" с инфинитивом может тоже сочетаться, поэтому думала что в целевых предложениях это тоже сосл. накл. 
Спасибо за исправление, поищу еще маериал на эту тему! 
подойдет как альтернатива к "уговорила" глагол "убедила"? 
@Galina: большая просьба: пишите мне просто, пожалуйста! пришлось спросить ту коллегу что значит "не ночевало сосл. накл." =)

Comment: Анонимушка! Я же таким макаром обучаю тебя разговорному языку, именно он самый главный пласт при изучении чужого языка, а ещё хлеще - просторечный! Самый вкусный для изучения! Насчёт "убедить": всё-таки предпочтительнее убедить сходить (как приехать купить), но, наверное, можно пережить и то (уговорить) и это (убедить) слово - словари-то позволяют. Желаю удачи в освоении  ВМПС им. Тургенева (так наш современный писатель определил язык по Тургеневу: Великий-Могучий-Правдивый-Свободный)!

Comment: Галина, Вы неправы. В целевых предложениях именно сослагательное наклонение :Иди тихо(зачем?), чтобы мама не заметила( бы) . БЫ здесь пропускается, потому что его уже содержит чтобы, так мы избавляемся от повтора;
и в дополнительных: Мама хочет, чтобы ты так не делал(бы);
и в некоторых других.

Answer (score 1):

Всё прекрасно сочетается, и так говорят.

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовала сделать обратно: из инфинитива к СПП цели.

Но вот цели у Вас как раз и не получилось:

(2) Я уговорила его (что сделать?) обратиться к психотерапевту. Это не вопрос цели, она здесь даже не мыслится.

Инфинитив цели употребляется обычно при глаголах движения: пошёл, поехал, вёз, нёс, появился и др.

Он пошёл в школу (зачем?) учиться. - Он пошёл в школу, чтобы учиться.
Здесь должен действовать один субъект (он пошёл, он учится)

Такая перестройка не получится, если будет два субъекта:

Она уехала (зачем?), чтобы все забыли о ней, - заменить вторую часть инфинитивом невозможно.

Comment: Люсенька, я ж этой терминологии вовсе не знаю... А вот последнее предложение, с невозможным инфинитивом: *Она уехала (зачем?), чтобы БЫТЬ всеми забытой*, - трохи искусственно, но не инфинитив разве ж?! О_о

Comment: Галя, речь о другой перестановке-замене придаточного обстоятельством цели.(по ссылочке автора вопроса перейти надо, там объясняется)Она уехала быть забытой - несколько не по-русски.

Answer (score 0):

**Замена правильная:** Я уговорила его обратиться к психотерапевту. →  Я уговорила его, чтобы он обратился к психотерапевту.

**УГОВОРИТЬ,** св. кого (что), (с инф.). Убеждая, склонить к чему-л., заставить согласиться с кем-, чем-л. У. больного на операцию. Друзья уговорили меня пойти в театр. Уговорил не жаловаться. Мы уговорили его на мороженое. Тотчас уговорили пойти с нами. **Уговорили, чтобы он приехал.**

В Нацкорпусе **такие примеры есть:** Ведь я едва ребят **уговорил, чтобы** они не пошли на помощь к тебе. [А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия (1943-1951)] http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F3%E3%EE%E2%EE%F0%E8%EB%2C+%F7%F2%EE%E1%FB